# How to get the opposite of VisibleItemsList - HiddenItemsList (1004)

Tags: vba, pivot-table

So, I've written some VB to filter a pivot table based on a range.

```
Worksheets("Collections By Timekeepers").PivotTables("Collections By Timekeepers").PivotFields(1).VisibleItemsList = arrFilters
```

Now I need to do the same but with HiddenItemsList, however, I'm getting a 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" despite being an OLAP cube.

```
Worksheets("Collections By Timekeepers").PivotTables("Collections By Timekeepers").PivotFields(2).HiddenItemsList = arrFilters
```

Is there a work around, or another way to exclude items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set .CubeField.IncludeNewItemsInFilter to True in order to do this. Suggest you check out my two recent answers on this:

This answer gives you the syntax:
[Pivot Table filter out only 1 option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404166/pivot-table-filter-out-only-1-option/48409297#48409297)

Note that you can't use this method on PageFields. But here's a workaround: This answer gives you a function to filter OLAP PivotTables no matter what kind of field they are:
[how to set PivotField.HiddenItemsList property's value if CubeField.Orientation = xlPageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317414/how-to-set-pivotfield-hiddenitemslist-propertys-value-if-cubefield-orientation/49346039#49346039)

Comment: You sir, are a life saver

Comment: Ahh, it's nuttin.